# Rospy subscriber needs sleep (some time) until the first message is received

Tags: ros, callbackqueue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I noticed following somehow strange behaviour. A topic subscriber is not ready to receive messages directly after its creation and needs some time until the first message can be received. The minimal example below illustrates this.

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo("I heard %s",data.data)
    
rospy.init_node('node_name')

pub = rospy.Publisher('topic_name', String, queue_size=10)

sub = rospy.Subscriber("topic_name", String, callback)

pub.publish("no delay")

rospy.sleep(1)

pub.publish("with delay")

rospy.spin()
```

Results in:

```
[INFO] [1483456752.613187]: I heard with delay
```

I would expect:

```
[INFO] [1483457135.695501]: I heard no delay
[INFO] [1483457135.696547]: I heard with delay
```

Is this behaviour correct, as it is somehow understandable that it needs time to initialize the callback thread for the subscriber, or is it actually a bug? Does exist a better way to solve this issue instead of using rospy.sleep?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251194/rospy-subscriber-needs-sleep-(some-time)-until-the-first-message-is-received/) by [chrisLB](https://answers.ros.org/users/20166/chrislb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2017-01-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-01-03**:
It's the normal behaviour. You can check for a listener with getNumSubscribers/Publishers. Could you also have a look at latched topics.

**Comment by [chrisLB](https://answers.ros.org/users/20166/chrislb/) on 2017-01-04**:
Thank you for the valuable hint! I answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The hint from @NEngelhard was correct, using the option latch=True results in what I had expected before. Thanks a lot!

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo("I heard %s",data.data)

rospy.init_node('node_name')

pub = rospy.Publisher('topic_name', String, queue_size=10, latch=True) # working as expected
#pub = rospy.Publisher('topic_name', String, queue_size=10) # not working as expected

sub = rospy.Subscriber("topic_name", String, callback)

pub.publish("no delay")

rospy.sleep(1)

pub.publish("with delay")

rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [chrisLB](https://answers.ros.org/users/20166/chrislb/) with karma: 46 on 2017-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1